# Decode RSA given e,p and q_inv ( with respect to p)

Tags: rsa

Suppose I was given e, p and q_inv. Where q_inv = 1 mod (p).
How would one go about computing N to decode the ciphertext?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you have some more information? Is this a home work problem? Could you post the whole exercise? Normally, p×q=N, and you would need d to decrypt. In your question, there is no N and no q, so you don't even seem to have a complete problem.

Answer (score 2):

In RSA $p$ and $q$ are chosen such that they are both prime numbers. I suspect that by $q_{inv}$ you mean the CRT coefficient, which is actually defined as $q_{inv} = q^{-1} \bmod{p}$. Thus, to find $q$ we need to calculate $q_{inv}^{-1} \bmod{p}$, and since $p$ is prime we can use Euler's Theorem to compute it as $q = q_{inv}^{p-2} \bmod{p}$. Note that this only works under the assumption that $p > q$, which is a standard assumption for RSA CRT. Knowing $p$ and $q$, we can now compute $N = p*q$.

Comment: "Note that this only works under the assumption that p>q, which is a standard assumption for RSA CRT"; actually, no, the standard CRT algorithm works no matter whether p or q is larger, and so many implementations aren't careful about the relative ordering.

Comment: However, when $p<q$, common practice is to still have $q<k\;p$ for some small $k$; thus $q=(q_{inv}^{-1}\bmod p)+j\;p$ for some small $j<k$. We also know that $q$ is prime, and usually that will allow to narrow down on a single $q$, or very few ones.

Comment: @poncho Sure, but $q \ne q_{inv}^{p-2} \bmod{p}$ if $q > p$, which is the context of what you quoted. You can still recover $q$ if $q > p$ but it requires different steps to recover, as fgrieu points out.

Comment: A common reference for RSA private key parameters for easy use of RSA CRT is [PKCS#1v2.2](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=6), which does not specify if $p<q$ or $p>q$ when it computes $q_\text{inv}=q^{-1}\bmod p$. [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf#page=62) does not specify if $p<q$ or $p>q$ either, and  gives a lower bound for $|p-q|$, confirming both orders are OK. However, when it mentions explicitly that it allows using RSA CRT, it gives no detail and has no mention of $q_\text{inv}$.